# I want to save the data 'self.billdata' into a file?? But with this code no data is being printed in to the file saved

Tags: python, tkinter, save-as

I want to save the data 'self.billdata' into a file?? But with this code no data is being printed in to the file saved

```py
def save_bill(self):
        self.billdata = self.txtarea.get('1.0',END)
        files = [('All Files', '*.*'), 
                 ('Python Files', '*.py'),
                 ('Text Document', '*.txt')]
        file = asksaveasfile(filetypes = files, defaultextension = ".txt")
        f1 = open(file,'w')
        f1.write(self.billdata)
        f1.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for me working

```
    print(You Data", file=open(""+str("FILE NAME")+".txt", "a", encoding='utf-8'))
```